# How to find a process that holds a certain port on windows vista so I can run vnc

Tags: windows, port, vnc

I am trying to run VNC at 5900, but allegedly some process is holding it, thus vnc complains: NOT accepting connections.

how to fix that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Is it already installed as a service, but you're launching it as a client?  The service will already have the port open.
- Is the built-in firewall interfering?
- As a temporary work-around, have you considered just bumping the display port by 1?  This serves as a diagnostic - if you can connect to {host IP}:5901 just fine, then most likely the port really is taken.  If that host-port combo also fails, then it's more likely your firewall is causing you grief.

Answer (score 6):

start -> run -> cmd -> netstat -b

Comment: you can use netstat -o as well in combination with task manager.

Answer (score 1):

TCPView from sysinternals - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx

The entire sysinternals suite is highly recommended.

Answer (score 0):

download and run cports which is available [here](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/cports.zip).  this will tell you what process is listening on what ports.

Answer (score 0):

sure there are other tools but http://www.netlimiter.com/ is one tool i have used in the past